# Error in plugin for WooCommerce

Tags: php

I have recently started to write plugin for woocommerce  and everything worked flawlessly **before I tried to hook the extension to the system**.

*I have a following code inside my class*.

```
function add_gateway($methods)
{
  $methods[]  = 'Rentalbloom_WSPay';
  return $methods;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_gateway');
```

Class has constructor defined as a **`public function __contruct()`** so it shouldn't have problems with the access, but when I try to run this I get the following error.

**`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION`** and the error points to the add_filter line written above.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using a PHP version 5.3 on the APMPPS stack on the OS X.

Comment: SOLVED: I needed to remove the add_filter call out of the main class.

Comment: Didn't see this! Glad you got it working, woocommerce is great carry on developing with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public function __contruct()` has a typo should be con**s**truct
Soo..
`public function __construct()`

You also mentioned

> I have a following code inside my class.

You need to ensure that filters sit outside of the class scope.

So move `add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_gateway');`